# What are the architecture options for express + socket.io + mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm developing a MMO game that needs continous socket connection with the server.

There are some requirements for my architechture.

1. User Authentication over socket.io connection.
2. Realtime user interaction with each other.
3. Must handle MASSIVE amount of calculations and database CRUD operations.
4. I am targeting modern browsers and planing to use new technologies and old known performance increaser technics like Web workers, Web sockets, Local storage, Link prefetching, Data URI.

The question is:

What are the recommended methods and modules for that kind of application?

Thanx and sorry for my poor language skills.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to go down with node if you need massive amounts of calculations? Other systems are generally a lot better at that, Node is great for I/O but not so much for CPU intensive tasks.

Comment: @Roel van Uden you know the application lifespawn. I don't expect to serve millions of users on one server or over Nodejs forever. But javascript is my best tool for start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [express.io](http://express-io.org).

It's a realtime-web framework that makes it easy to combine express & socket.io.  Which means that your regular web and realtime web components should play nicely together.

It has session support and routing features.  Also, there is a lot of documentation and example code.

It's way simpler to setup a basic app, then using both libraries separately.

```
app = require('express.io')
app.http().io()

// your game code goes here :)

app.listen(7076)
```

For mongo, my favorite is [mongo-skin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin), but [mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose) is also very popular.

Best of Luck!

DISCLAIMER: I wrote it :)

Comment: intrestingly this is the solution that I'm examining just right now :)